# changing 2.29.0 prisma version to 1.12.0

Tags: prisma

Can you explain how can we change the prisma version on linux? For now, the version is 2.29.0 but this must be 1.12.0.   2.29.0 installed with *npm install -g prisma@2.29.0*

Comment: Not sure why this go the [nuxt.js] tag and all the others. What did you look for so far? Did you googled how to remove a globally installed package? And how to then install a specific one?

Comment: You are right. I found the prisma file with  $which prisma, i tried  $rm -r bin/prisma bin/prisma2 .  Do you know anything about that?

Comment: This is not the way you should uninstall it IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove existing version of Prisma with this command

```
npm uninstall -g prisma
```

Now install the specific version you want with this.

```
npm install prisma@1.12.0
```

Optionally add the -g flag if you want to install it globally. But this isn't really recommended.

Additionally, I'd recommend using Prisma version 2 as Prisma version 1 is in maintenance mode and no longer actively developed.